# Finding a Perpendicular vector with 2 cordinates already

Tags: math

i'm trying to practice my math for my upcoming exam, and i have an example that i'm trying to work out.

I'm trying to find an angle of exactly 90% (making vector B perpendicular to vector A)

A = (1, 3, 2)
B = (2, x, -2)

I've tried x = 0, x = 0.5, x = 1. I can't seem to get the Dot product to equal 0 (making them perpendicular of course).

Can anyone shed some light on how i can find "x" to make A and B 90 degree between each other?

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [math](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: "I've tried x = 0, x = 0.5, x = 1" have you never been taught basic algebraic methods? You should be able to rearrange the equation to solve for x.

Comment: No i have not. I didn't do well in math at high school, and sadly this unit at uni is mandatory. I had no say in taking it or not

Comment: You want the `cross` product not the `dot` product to impose orthogonality. A `dot` product provides only a scalar, the dot product will provide points guaranteed to be orthogonal to those input. (it's the old "find a plane perpendicular to a point" problem from calculus). See: [**Cross Product**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)

Comment: @David I am not normally this blunt, but shut up if you don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: My friend, I have had more math than you will ever have an opportunity in life to experience. Did you read the link provided, or did you just rely on setting the dot product to zero because that is the only formula you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really should be on [math.stackexchange](http://www.math.stackexchange.com), but someone else can move it. Just compute the dot product of the vectors:

`(1, 3, 2) dot (2, x, -2) = 0`

`2 + 3x - 4 = 0`

`x = 2/3`

Comment: x = 2/3 but what is that in terms of coordinates? I don't understand how to convert that into a coordinate

Comment: `x` is the y-coordinate in the vector you gave. So 2/3 is the y-coordinate for that vector.